# Microsoft Access After Insert Macro to Insert Multiple Records into a Different Table Based on Template Table

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to set up my table 'project_detail' to execute a macro after a record is inserted. The macro must insert multiple records into a table based on another table that contains a template definition.

For example:

tbl_project_detail

When a record is inserted into project_detail, baseline_project should be populated with 4 tasktypeno because it is defined in task_template.

```
 modno | .... |
 --------------
   a     ....
```

tbl_baseline_project

```
| modno | tasktypeno |
------------------
    a        1
    a        2
    a        3
    a        4
```

tbl_task_template

```
| tasktypeno | task_class | task_name |
      1            ...          ...
      2            ...          ...
      3            ...          ...
      4            ...          ...
```

I'd prefer to have this done through a macro, however doing this through VBA will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by following this post.

http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=2021865